Logical structure of definition of sequence convergence
This question pops up as from trying prove the statement, that $\exists \epsilon>0,N \in \mathbb{N},\forall n \geq N,|x_n-x|\geq \epsilon$, then the sequence has no subsequence converges to $x$.
This statement does not negate convergence, since we can certainly have a bounded non-convergent sequence with a convergent subsequence. I understand the negation should be $\exists \epsilon>0,\forall N \in \mathbb{N},\exists n \geq N,|x_n-x|\geq \epsilon$, but I'm struggle to understand the logical structure of it, especially the last two statements.
Back to the definition, I think it is a compound statement of following form:$\forall p \exists q\forall r$?$s$. $p$ stands for condition on $\epsilon$,$q$ on $N$ we choose,$r$ on $n$, but what is the relation between $s$ the bound? Is it an AND or a $\Rightarrow$ ? Or it is a $(\forall p \exists q \forall r)\Rightarrow s$?

A bound on $\exists$ always means AND ($\wedge$), and a bound on $\forall$ always means “implies” ($\Rightarrow$). That is, the statement, fully expanded out, would be $\exists \epsilon (\epsilon > 0 \wedge (\forall N (N \in \mathbb{N} \Rightarrow (\exists n (n \geq N \wedge |x_n - x| \geq \epsilon)))))$.
